# How to return custom error messages in dotnet core Web Api

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I am writing a web api using dot net core. The functionality is simple when users enter and invalid username or password I want to return, invalid username or password as a json response. How can I do this in dot net core, I have managed to return this

> Invalid username or password

How can I return this instead

> `{   "message": "Invalid Login credentials!" }`

this is my controller

```
  [HttpPost]
            [Route("/api/[controller]/signin")]
            public async Task<IActionResult> Login([FromBody] LoginViewModel loginmodel)
            {
                if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    //return BadRequestModelState();
                    return Conflict(new ErrorViewModel("Wrong data sent"));
                }
    
    
                Users user = await _userService.GetByEmail(loginmodel.Username);
                if (user == null)
                {
                   
                    return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password");
                }
    
                bool isCorrectPassword = _passwordHasher.VerifyPassword(loginmodel.Password, user.Password);
                if (!isCorrectPassword)
                {
                    return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, "Invalid username or password");
                }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the simplest ways

```
return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status401Unauthorized, new { message = "Invalid username or password" });
```

Comment: How are you able to read the message string on the client when handling the response in JS?